# ScheduledFuture.get() is still blocked after Executor shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to run some periodic task in background and I want to do it right.
So I schedule my task with `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(..)` and call `ScheduledFuture.get()` on the separate thread to control the life of the task, catch uncaught exceptions from it and get notified if the task is cancelled.

The problem is that if `ScheduledExecutorService.shutdown()` is called while the task is executing, than `ScheduledFuture` does not get notified and its `get()` method stays blocked forever.

And here comes the simple code to illustrate the problem:

```
public final class SomeService {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private final SomePeriodicTask task = new SomePeriodicTask();
    private ScheduledFuture<?> future;

    public void start() {
        future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        final Runnable watchdog = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    future.get();
                } catch (CancellationException ex) {
                    System.out.println("I am cancelled");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("I am interrupted");
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    System.out.println("I have an exception");
                }
                System.out.println("Watchdog thread is exiting");
            }
        };
        new Thread(watchdog).start();
    }

    public void shutdownAndWait() {
        System.out.println("Shutdown requested");
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { //BTW When and why could this happen?
            System.out.println("Waiting for shutdown was interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Executor is shutdown " + executor.isShutdown());
    }
}
```

First, simple task which returns quickly

```
final class SomePeriodicTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("I am just doing my job...");
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

If we run it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SomeService service = new SomeService();
    service.start();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    service.shutdownAndWait();
    System.out.println("Future is cancelled " + service.future.isCancelled());
    System.out.println("Future is done " + service.future.isDone());
}
```

then the output is

```
I am just doing my job...done
I am just doing my job...done
I am just doing my job...done
Shutdown requested
I am cancelled
Watchdog thread is exiting
Executor is shutdown true
Future is cancelled true
Future is done true
```

totally as expected.

But if we modify the task to simulate some heavy job

```
final class SomePeriodicTask implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("I am just doing my job...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500); //Heavy job. You can change it to 5000 to be sure
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Task was interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

so that the call to `shutdown()` happens while the task is executing... then the output is

```
I am just doing my job...done
I am just doing my job...Shutdown requested
done
Executor is shutdown true
Future is cancelled false
Future is done false
```

So what happened here... Executor is shutting down, as expected. It lets the current task to finish its job, as expected. We see that executor did finish shutting down, but our `ScheduledFuture` did not get cancelled and its `get()` method is still blocked and the watchdog thread prevents JVM from exiting and hangs forever.

Of course there are workarounds. For example I can call `future.cancel(false)` manually before shutdown or make `watchdog` a daemon thread or even try to schedule shutdown of Executor by himself so that it does not overlap with running task... But all of above have drawbacks and when code will get more complicated things can go sideways.

And anyway, I am seeking for your expert opinion because I will have no peace until I understand why it doesn't behave like it should. If it is a bug in jdk it must be reported. If I misunderstand something and my code is wrong, I must know it...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to understand is that for a *periodic* task, a normal completion does not turn the state of the `Future` to `done` as it expects to be rescheduled and possibly rerun.

This interferes with the semantics of `Executor.shutdown`; it will `cancel` all *pending* tasks but let the currently running tasks complete. So your currently running task completes normally and doesn’t set its state to `done` as it never does, but isn’t rescheduled because the executor has been shut down.

Even if you use `shutdownNow` it will interrupt the currently running tasks but not cancel them and since your task catches the `InterruptedException` and completes earlier but normally, there will be no state transition to `done`.

The best place to add the desired behavior of cancelling even tasks that completed normally upon shutdown is the `Executor` implementation; just change the line

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

to

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1) {
  @Override
  protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    if(t==null && isShutdown() && r instanceof RunnableScheduledFuture<?>)
    {
      RunnableScheduledFuture<?> rsf = (RunnableScheduledFuture<?>)r;
      if(rsf.isPeriodic()) rsf.cancel(false);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: @Holder Thanks a lot for your help, but it does not answer my question. The question was why is ScheduledFuture.get() indefinitely blocked even when Executor clearly and properly shutdown and gone long time ago. It should return null or throw some kind of exception or whatever you name it, but not just hang there forever. This behavior is not properly documented and looks really wrong and faulty to me. I tend to consider it as a bug. I am printing the state of the future just for verbosity, to show that the future does not get any notification of shutdown. I don't care about its actual...

Comment: ...state. Probably it is confusing and I should have left it out. Your solution is again a workaround. I mentioned three of them in my question and you proposed the fourth. There must be more of them, but I still wish to know why `ScheduledFuture.get()` is deadly blocked upon shutdown and why it is considered as proper behavior.

Comment: I *did* explain the behavior. It doesn’t matter whether *you* care about the state of the future but *the future* cares. It’s `get` method will never return as long as the future isn’t completed. And the periodic future doesn’t complete. Point.

Comment: If you don’t want workarounds, don’t create a “watchdog”. And never call `get` on the future of a periodic task as it’s clear that it never can complete normally.